# Symfony validation: First property constraint then class constraint

Tags: validation, symfony, constraints

I'm using Symfony 2.5 and my Model class is the following:

```
/**
 * @UserAssert\UserPasswordReset
*/
class ResetPassword {

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
public $username;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Date
 */
public $birthday;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
public $plainSecurityAnswer;


function __toString()
{
    return $this->username . $this->birthday->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . $this->plainSecurityAnswer;
}
```

}

This Model is mapped to a ResetFormType.
Now my intention: How can i say / configure, that i first want the property constraints to be passed. And if all property constraints are passed (e.g. no field is blank), i want the @UserAssert\UserPasswordReset to be called.

At the moment, it always validates the property AND the class constraints.

Regards ++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do it using a [GroupSequence Validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#group-sequence) like this:

```
/**
 * @UserAssert\UserPasswordReset(groups={"PasswordReset"})
 * @Assert\GroupSequence({"Default", "PasswordReset"})
 */
class ResetPassword
{
    //----
}
```

In this mode `UserPasswordReset` will be validated only after the Defaults Asserts.

In the docs you will find some implementations example to use groups sequences..

Comment: thanks alot! That's what i was looking for. Damn i looked up the documentation but overread GroupSequences .. -.- Accepted your answer.

Comment: glad to be helpful :-)